# how the event bubbling and phases occurred in html

Tags: javascript, html

How are events and phases triggered according to the events?

like every objects created in tree with their handles and if you click on one button all events linked in that div are triggered.

I have made program which have different sub div and having one paragraph and button.

I have came across different theories for event bubbling like [event bubbling explained](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: Check [this article by ppk](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) also read the related articles and introduction to events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Example
in HTML, elements are nested inside other elements like so

```
<div id="outer">
   <h1 id="inner">Inner<h1>
</div>
```

when an event on an inner element is triggered it affects every outer element as you might have read in the post you linked. This is bubbling. Event flow can be controlled by

```
var element = document.getElementById('inner');
element.addEventListener("event",yourFunction, false);
```

here, `false` means event flow is from the inner element (on which event is fired) to the outer elements. this is the default in all browsers.

to stop bubbling you could use `stopPropagation()`

Comment: perfect example.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Event Bubble and Phases</title>
        <script>
            function f1() {
                console.log("f1");
                console.log("Current Element " + event.currentTarget.id);
                console.log("Target "+event.target.id);
                console.log("Event Phase "+event.eventPhase);
                console.log("Bubble Status "+event.bubbles);
                console.log("Cancelable Status "+event.cancelable);
            }
            function f2() {
                console.log("f2");
                console.log("Current Element " + event.currentTarget.id);
                console.log("Target "+event.target.id);
                console.log("Event Phase "+event.eventPhase);
                console.log("Bubble Status "+event.bubbles);
                console.log("Cancelable Status "+event.cancelable);
            }
            function f3() {
                console.log("f3");
                console.log("Current Element " + event.currentTarget.id);
                console.log("Target "+event.target.id);
                console.log("Event Phase "+event.eventPhase);
                console.log("Bubble Status "+event.bubbles);
                console.log("Cancelable Status "+event.cancelable);
            }
            function f4() {
                console.log("f4");
                console.log("Current Element " + event.currentTarget.id);
                console.log("Target "+event.target.id);
                console.log("Event Phase "+event.eventPhase);
                console.log("Bubble Status "+event.bubbles);
                console.log("Cancelable Status "+event.cancelable);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1" onclick="f1()" style="background-color: brown; color: aliceblue;padding:20px">
            This is div at level1
            <div id="div2" onclick="f2()" style="background-color: burlywood;padding:20px">
                This is div at level2
                <p id="paragraph1" onclick="f3()" style="background-color: appworkspace;padding:20px">
                    <button id="button1" onclick="f4()" style="background-color: beige;padding:20px">   
                        Click 
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "it's working" if it throws four error messages ..? Btw. Something to [read about events and event bubbling](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).